# Unclear error when defining a custom Ordered type in Scala

Tags: scala, types

```
implicit class OrderableFoo[T<:Foo[A,_] forSome {type A <: Ordered[A]}](thisFoo:Foo)
extends Ordered[Foo]{
override def compare(other:Foo):Int = thisFoo.value.compare(other.value)
}
```

My issue:

thisFoo.value returns a value of type A

Type A is ordered

thisFoo.value.compare is expecting an argument of type A

other.value is of type A

thisFoo.value.compare(other.value) will not compile. "Expected A but received Ordered[A]"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, when using the forSome {type} feature, thisFoo's A is not the same as other's A. All we know is that both A's are orderable. This can be fixed by supplying other type parameters.